# What is the difference between call hierarchy and find references eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I got confused when using this two commands in `eclipse` <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> both are returning same results .

**Scenario**:

Want to find where the method "**findUsage**" has been called.

**Sample Class**

[image]

**Call Hierarchy Output (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>)** .

[image]

**Find References (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>) output**

[image]

Both are showing same results. Can anyone know what is the difference between these two commands?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

"Find references" shows you all **direct callers** of the selected method. "Call hierarchy" in contrast shows also the callers of those direct callers, and the callers of those, ... and so on.

So the output is only identical, if direct callers of your selected method do not have any callers themselfes. Just try both commands on some larger code base and you will immmediately see the difference, like in this screenshot:

[image: Call hierarchy]

If you wonder why there are two such features, if "Find references" is basically just a subset of the "Call hierarchy": Find references works really fast, so you can use it all the time without any waiting for results. The call hierarchy on the other hand takes more computation time and therefore may interrupt your coding workflow.

Comment: "Find References" exists more because it has other uses as well...there is no such thing as a call hierarchy of a field, but you can find references to it. Another difference is that the Call Hierarchy can be set to forward mode as well, showing what methods the selected method calls, what methods those call, etc.

Comment: AFAIK Call Hierarchy finds field references.

Answer (score 1):

- **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>** : Reference in workspace.  It shows only **references** of selected  class or method or variable in source code.
- **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>** : Call **H**ierarchy. It shows all **hierarchy** up to root class.